# Is there any Sorted List in C# that allows the sorting to ocurr as we are adding the elements to it?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

Is there any Sorted List in C# that allows the sorting to ocurr as we are adding the elements to it? What I mean with this is that I don't want a List that has a .Sort() method, but a List that will actually put the items in the right place when I'm adding them to it (I guess internally it'll have some kind of a tree).

Here is my scenario:

```
class Worker {
    ...some fields
    public int salary;
}
```

I'd like to add workers to my list, and have them be sorted by their salaries.
I'd like then to do list[0] and know that that worker is the one with the highest salary. Then do list[1] and know that'll be the one with the second highest salary, etc.

Is there any data structure in C# that accomplishes this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Sorted List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) class in .Net

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to want a *collection of workers* rather than a *map from salary to worker*, I would go with [**`SortedSet<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx). To get the data-structure to order by salary, make the `Worker` class implement `IComparable<Worker>`.  Alternatively, write an `IComparer<Worker>` and get the SortedSet to use that instead. Do note that this class dos *not* support fast access by *index*, so you'll have to use something else if this is  an important requirement.

EDIT:
Thinking about it, going with a `SortedList<int, Worker>` or a `SortedDictionary<int, Worker>` is *not* appropriate here since they don't support duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) says about `System.Collections.SortedList` :

When an element is added, it is inserted into SortedList in the correct sort order, and the indexing adjusts accordingly.

But what you need should be implemented as a smart class which is familiar with `worker` class.

Answer (score 0):

Closest you'll get (not technically a list) is the [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx)`<TKey, TValue>` class (which is the generic version of SortedList listed in other questions).